DFL FFmpeg failed
I get this error when Merged video to MP4, this is the first time i had this error and it keeps happening

/!\ ffmpeg fail, job commandline:['ffmpeg', '-f', 'image2pipe', '-r', '30000/1001', '-i', 'pipe:', '-i', 'G:\DeepFaceLab_DirectX12\workspace\data_dst.mp4', '-map', '0', '-map', '1:1', '-ar', '48000', '-b:a', '192k', '-b:v', '16M', '-c:a', 'aac', '-c:v', 'libx264', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '-strict', 'experimental', 'G:\DeepFaceLab_DirectX12\workspace\result.mp4', '-y']

sorry for my bad eng, pls help me
